# Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name TokenRelay

Tags: oauth, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Hey I am trying to achieve the below use case

**Use Case**: Verify incoming request JWT in spring cloud Gateway
**Approach**: Invoke Authorization server using Tokenrelay filter

**Problem**: Getting an error while trying to configure Token relay based on https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/reference/html/#_token_relay

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name TokenRelay
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name TokenRelay
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.loadGatewayFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:187) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.getFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:228) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.convertToRoute(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:170) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.3.13.RELEASE.jar:3.3.13.RELEASE]
```

Here are my sample application details

```
**build.gradle**

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.8.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

```
applicaiton.yml

spring:
  application:
    name: spring-cloud-gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: user
          uri: http://localhost:8081/
          predicates:
            - Path=/ugp-api/v1/**
            - Query=src
          filters:
          - TokenRelay
          - AddResponseHeader=Cache-Control,max-age=10
  security:
   oauth2:
    resource:
      jwt:
        key-uri: http://localhost:9000/auth/v1/oauth/token_key
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATKDV.png)

Comment: for now, you may try with adding Jose dependency